# Unable to get all Facebook friends in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-friends

In my application I have an option to get all Facebook friends. So I want to my all Facebook friends. But enable to get all friend.
I am using API version v2.4 and when I was check API in Facebook graph explore its give me response like this:

**Graph API** : `v2.4/me?fields=friends`

**Response :**

```
{
      "friends": {
        "data": [
        ],
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 200
        }
      },
      "id": "1700734103483027"
}
```

Total count is right, but list is not showing.
Graph API gives debug message like this **"Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app.Learn More"**.

So how can I get all Facebook friends?

Comment: You can not get all facebook friend. You can only get the friends which are using your application.

Comment: Now , is there any option ? how to get all Facebook friends

Comment: I don't think so. Facebook changed the permissions check the answer below.

Comment: yes , below answer already checked :) 
thanks for the response

Comment: but Facebook friend list display in instagram then there is any way available to get all friend

Comment: Check instagram also don't display whole list. I am not using instagram. my friends don't get me in the list. @stela

Comment: @Ashish Kakkad :Then what is the meaning of "invite friend" functionality if all friends will not be listed in list

Comment: I want to get all friends using the User Acess Token. Whether that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

**Facebook changed the permissions. 
You can not get all Facebook friend.**

You can only get the friends which are using your application.

From the Facebook documents :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4

> **user_friends**
>
> Provides access the list of friends that also use your app. These
>   friends can be found on the [friends edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends) on the user object.
>
> In order for a person to show up in one person's friend list, both
>   people must have decided to share their list of friends with your app
>   and not disabled that permission during login. Also both friends must
>   have been asked for user_friends during the login process. Review
>
> Your app may use this permission without review from Facebook. Common
>   Usage
>
> Use the list of friends to create a social experience in your app.

Also described in the

> **read_custom_friendlists**
>
> Provides access to the names of custom lists a person has created to
>   organize their friends. This is useful for rendering an audience
>   selector when someone is publishing stories to Facebook from your app.
>
> **This permission does not give access to a list of person's friends.** **If**
>   **you want to access a person's friends who also use your app, you**
>   **should use the user_friends permission.**
>
> This permission will also not help you invite a person's friends to
>   use your app. To learn more about how to invite friends to an app,
>   please see our FAQs.
>
> This permission also does not give the list of friends who are part of
>   a friendlist. It only gives access to the names of the lists.
>
> This permission was called read_friendlists before v2.3

Comment: I want to get all friends using the User Acess Token. Whether that is possible?